# Calculation to find the draft value of a fantasy football player

Tags: algorithms, scoring-algorithm

I'm a programmer working on an online fantasy football draft board. In this I would like to find the best and worst draft pick per team based on the projected number of fantasy points for the drafted player and the round that he was taken.

It seemed like a relatively easy problem to solve (and it probably is for y'all), but I am unable to :(.

So here are my thoughts:

```
| Round | Fantasy Points | Draft Value |  
----------------------------------------  
|   1   |       300      |      85     |  
|   2   |       250      |      86     |  
|   3   |       200      |      86     |  
|   4   |       210      |      93     | 
|   5   |       150      |      85     |  
.....
|   12  |       250      |      99     |
```

So basically, round 1 you will obviously get a player with a high projection of points, but that doesn't necessarily make it the best draft value. If you were to, say, in the 12th round draft someone with a projected 250 fantasy points, then that would be a much higher draft value than a number 1 pick of 300.

Make sense?

Is there a formula for doing this?

Comment: It is a tougher algorithm than you might guess.  The stupid simple algorithm would say, if you didn't take the best available player based on fantasy points, that was a bad pick.  But the reality is, the question of what is available in each position vs. what I expect might be available in each position by the time of my next pick.

Comment: I'm not worried about what was available at the specific time, but more just an overall look at who was drafted and when. I'm only worried about the 96 draft picks and putting a value on them based on the round they were drafted. Maybe down the road it can turn into a complex algorithm that values based on who was available at the time the pick was made, but not today!

Answer (score -1):

You could compare the projection with the average value of the positional draft slot. So, say the 5th QB taken has over the past 5 seasons scored 290 points, if the projection is 300, then the value would be +10. You could then compare that surplus value to that of the next RB#, WR#, and TE# on the board. Just keep in mind that not all projections are equal (for example, QB scoring is more predictable than RB scoring).